# rails form helper color_field not pulling value through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I have class named 'Color' which inherits from String, it takes and returns a color hex string.

I have the following model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  def color
    Color.new(self[:color])
  end

end
```

And I have the following view for the category edit form:

```
<%= form_for @category, url: @category do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :color %>:
  <%= f.color_field :color %>
<% end %>
```

Whatever I set the 'color' to for the Category, the color_field always returns black. I'm guessing that nil is getting passed to the field and black is just the default value?

The odd thing is if I change the color_field to text_field the hex string pulls through as expected. If I call @category.color, @category::color, @category[:color] or @category.send :color I also receive the hex string as expected so I can't work out where the black (or nil) is coming from.

Comment: `<%= f.color_field :color, value:  @category.color%>` can you try this?

Comment: Yeah, that works fine. Although I'm curios as to why the value needs to be called directly. I expect the color_field helper must be calling the :color method in an unexpected way? if I define color in the model as a plain string:
`def color
    "#FF0000'
end`

it pulls through okay, so it must be something to do with it being in a custom class?

Comment: is `@category` a new record? or an existing record?

Comment: Do you allow me to write answer for it, for future SO searcher as well?

Comment: In this instance it's an existing record, but the same happens with a new record too. And yeah, I'm more than happy for you to write an answer.

Comment: can you comment your color method which is defined in Category model and try it?

Comment: Is Color.new(self[:color]) returning a string or an object? It should return a string, no?

Comment: Possibly remove it from the constructor, like Color.get_color(self[:color]) which returns the hex color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[color_field](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/color_field)

Here is an example

```
f.color_field :color

# => <input id="color" name="color" type="color" value="#000000" />
```

So by default it takes `value="#000000"` to override it need to pass explicitly

```
<%= f.color_field :color, value: @category.color%>
```

Reference: -
http://railsdoc.com/references/color_field

*correct me if i'm wrong***

Comment: But why doesn't it take the value from the color method?

Comment: @Joel_Blum Something is wrong with color method which is defined in Category model.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to mark this as correct as it gets around the problem, but the fault seems to be somewhere inside my Color class returning an object rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are not returning a string here but an object

```
def color
   Color.new(self[:color]) //returns object
end
```

Maybe you can define a to_s method on Color class (that returns the hex) and then do

```
def color
  Color.new(self[:color].to_s) //returns hex
end
```

Comment: Okay yeah, this seems to be something to do with it. The thing is I need color to act exactly like a string but with a few extra methods. I.e I need to be able to call `@category.color.inverse` to return the inverse of the color. Obviously this wont work if I'm setting to_s in the getter method.

I may have got myself in a muddle here.

Comment: maybe using @Gabbar's solution is easiest in this instance.  If you want a more canonical way of doing this perhaps look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html because it's pretty close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. For the time being I've just removed the inheritance from String and manually added the methods I need and it all seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a value with color in hex representation:

```
value: "##{@banner.body_color}"
```